# Facebook SDK Swift - Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift, bridging-header

**I am getting `Use of undeclared identifier` for every Facebook Object I use**

Following this tutorial:
[TUTORIAL: HOW TO SHARE IN FACEBOOK SDK 4.1.X FOR SWIFT](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-share-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/)

But I've got the following error:

[image]

I've added Facebook framework via cocoapods:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

And it was installed successfully

[image]

I've added bridging header

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

The bridging header is connected:

[image]

I've configured my .plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb*****</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>*****</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>*****</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>  <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Here is the code:

```
let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
        content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "<INSERT STRING HERE>")
        content.contentTitle = "<INSERT STRING HERE>"
        content.contentDescription = "<INSERT STRING HERE>"
        content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "<INSERT STRING HERE>")

        let button : FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
        button.shareContent = content
        button.frame = CGRectMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 100) * 0.5, 50, 100, 25)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: did you run pod install or try running it again

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot I did. It worked fine. The frameworks are in my Pods project

Comment: So is it solved and did it resolve by running  pod install again ?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot, No. Getting the framework with pod was not the problem. The problem is that the framework is not recognized

Comment: Confirm the following:

 1. Linker Flag in Build Settings is set to -ObjC
 2. import statements are present at the top of your swift files for the facebook resources you are trying to call

Comment: @Kashif, 1.I have -ObjC linked flag 2. No. What exactly should I import? .h files in Swift?

Comment: When I do it (for example import FBSDKAccessToken.h), it writes "No such module 'FBSDKAccessToken.h'".

Comment: are you in swift or objective-C? Could you provide an example of the code you are trying to write?

Comment: Can you please show me 2 objects your getting the **Use of undeclared identifier**, I need evaluate what header import your missing

Comment: This has nothing to do with your **.plist**

Comment: @thibautnoah, I've updated the question with my error and code

Comment: @FarhadNezhad , I've updated the question

Comment: @Luda Sound like someone answer it :) Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks I found my answer from your Question. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use Pods and your project is on Swift you don't need to import headers from pods to **Bridging_Header_h**
It's suficient to import needed SDK to you swift file like:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit
```

Comment: This is true. Also, you can go head and even initiate a variable for the classes. Nice catch Lurie.

Answer (score 5):

First step is create Podfile, for example:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift'
pod 'GBDeviceInfo'
```

Save file and install or update pods by command:

```
pod install / pod update
```

Next, you should add in general settings framework:

[image]

Comment: I've added the frameworks where you sugested, but it dodn't help :( http://i65.tinypic.com/20l1idk.png

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift** users: Facebook Swift SDK `0.7.0` and `0.8.0` seem to be completely FUBAR, there is no way to get imports to work properly even on a completely new project.

Revert to `0.6.0` by specifying the following in your `Podfile`, and the tutorials and imports will work again:

```
pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.6.0'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.6.0'
pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at it too until I found that it is a debug and release issue.

instead of using

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

You should use

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

Comment: Moving the imports out of the #ifndef block is why this works. The block then has no purpose, and could be deleted in the interest of compact, clear code